# How to solve error 0x8007042b while connecting a Google account on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, gmail

I recently updated to Windows 10 and I'm quite fine with it.

Except for apps like Mail or Calendar. Upon starting them, they ask me which accounts should be used.

So I'd like to add my Google account, as this is my main calendar.

I press "Add", where it lists several possible services. Upon clicking on "Google", it instantly throws me an error, **without prompting me for credentials**:

[image]

*"Just put some happy fluffy clouds here..."
- Windows 10 Mail app Designers*

This should be the translated error message:

> Something went wrong
>
> We're sorry, but we weren't able to do that.
>
> Error code 0x8007042b.

The results of research on the interwebs often recommend to first create a 2-hand-shake-password if turned on in Google. Well, that won't suffice, as I don't have any option to make anything. I just click on "Add Google Account" and the error instantly appears.

**How can I get Google services working on Windows 10?**

Comment: Do you have 2-factor authentication enabled on your Google Account?  If you do then you can't use your account password but instead need to use an application password.  The need to do this of course isn't a new requirement in Windows 10 though.

Comment: I already adressed this in my question. I don't have ANY possibility to insert a username or password, as these forms don't appear. An error immediately interrupts it. BTW I don't have it activated.

Comment: So I take that answer to indicate you do have 2-factor authentication enabled on the Google Account?  You don't have what exactly activated?  I am asking these questions for a very specific purpose.  Please do your best to answer them.

Comment: Sorry to be not exactly. :) I do not have 2-factor on. I won't even show a dialog. While clicking "Add -> Google" the error appears.

Comment: Can you sign in your account in a browser and go to settings and can post pics of them, it would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I could, but it wouldn't change anything. It doesn't even connect to Google, the error throws immediately - no account info no nothing. It's BEFORE I enter all of this. :/

Comment: If he can’t even input his account name, 2-factor auth obviously isn’t part of the problem at all.

Comment: Is your Google e-mail address used to logon to your Microsoft account or set as an alias on the Microsoft account?

Comment: @Trollwut Did it ever show you the login window?

Comment: Never. It's been like this since I upgraded to Win10.

Comment: Oh erm... just wanted to add that I switched to Linux soon after the Win10 release, which made my whole PC experience better. My question is therefore obsolete. Maybe other fellows may find it important.

Comment: I got the error 0X80070490, after restetng then, uninstalling the calendar app, and trying to reinstall it. It worked after I rebooted the PC.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

1. Go to your users folder (e.g. C:\Users\John).
2. Right click, select properties, Security, Advanced.
3. Click Add, select entity, advanced, search.
4. Click on ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES, accept. Select Full Control and apply (Ignore errors trying to apply permissions).

Then:

1. Click on start and type “Services”.
2. Right click on “Services” and select “Run as Administrator”.
3. In the Services Window, look for Credential Manager Service and “Stop” it.
4. Restart the computer and “Start” the Credential Manager Service and set it to “Automatic”.
5. Restart the computer and it should work fine.

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-outlook_mail/cant-add-gmail-account-to-windows-10-mail-app/97d4e308-54a8-4afe-b74f-501b1ea0fa2a?page=12

Comment: This looks promising! Immediately after I switched to solely Linux, so can any other Win10 user with my problem confirm this?

Comment: it works for me!

Comment: This works because after upgrading to Windows 10 or copying files into your user folder from a backup, the permissions are not set correctly anymore.  It's best to just apply the new permissions and replace all permissions with inheritable permissions.  You may not even have to go past step 4

Comment: I was wondering about the security ramifications of this, but the `All Application Packages` group _is_ supposed to have full control of `C:\Users`, [according to Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2798317).

Comment: It works for me too. I am digusted with the kind of bugs and lack of info Microsoft put

Comment: It took me forever to apply permissions, along with the bunch of warning messages that I had to handle manually throughout the whole process... and in the end, it didn't even work.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do two things here.

1. I have two factor authentication enabled for my google account, so I needed to set up a one time password for the Windows mail app. I went into my Google accounts settings. This link worked for me:

https://myaccount.google.com/security

Then go into "App Passwords" (under "Password and sign in method") and follow the prompts to create a password. You choose "Mail" on my "Windows Computer" from the dropdowns.

Leave that password on the screen, I needed it for the next step.

2. Create an IMAP account.

I couldn't connect to my Google account directly. I got the same error as you. None of the fixes I found on the web worked. So I created a new IMAP account. Go to

Settings (Cog icon) ->  Accounts -> Add Account -> Advanced Setup -> Internet Email

Now fill in the details. These are the values I used:

- Account Name: {any string like "My Gmail"}
- Your Name: {your name like "Fred Bloggs"}
- Incoming Mail Server: **imap.gmail.com:993**
- Account Type: **IMAP4**
- User name: {your gmail address}
- Password: {the one time password you just generated, otherwise just your gmail password}
- Outgoing SMTP email server: **smtp.gmail.com:465**
- All checkboxes checked

I have used the settings which work for people with a google apps account. If you have problems connecting to the gmail IMAP server, perhaps you need different settings. Google walks you through the settings here:

https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en&ref_topic=3397500

Good luck!

Comment: I do appreciate this doesn't solve getting your calendar synced, but this solution definitely gets mail working.

Comment: Thanks for that info! Unfortunatelly, the calendar is more important to me than the mails. And I would like to connect them accounts "naturally".

Comment: I have trawled the web for an answer to this one, and there are some suggestions that this is a (Windows) account related issue occurring when you have upgraded from a previous version of Windows. Some people have reported this working fine if you create a new Windows account or reinstall Windows 10...! I can't be bothered to do that so I will be waiting for a fix from Microsoft unless someone cleverer than me works it out first.

Comment: He wants the calendar synced also

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I found the solution on the web. This worked for me: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-outlook_mail/cant-add-gmail-account-to-windows-10-mail-app/97d4e308-54a8-4afe-b74f-501b1ea0fa2a?page=12

Comment: I'm getting annoyed that everywhere I go this is posted as a "solution". Lets be clear, this is not a solution, this is a workaround. This does NOT fix the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me whereas all others did not.

### Go to your Google Account page

1. Click <kbd>Security</kbd>
2. Enable <kbd>2-factor verification</kbd> at this step.
3. <kbd>App passwords</kbd>
4. <kbd>Mail</kbd>
5. <kbd>Windows Computer</kbd>
6. <kbd>Generate</kbd>
7. Copy the generated code.
8. <kbd>Done</kbd>
9. Open Mail in Windows and click on the cog wheel <kbd>⚙</kbd> → <kbd>manage accounts</kbd> → <kbd>+ add account</kbd> → <kbd>Other account</kbd>
10. Enter your email address associated with the code, your perferred name and lastly paste the password you copied in step 7.
11. <kbd>Sign in</kbd>

## Images showing above steps 1-8 in your google account

[image]

## Images showing above steps 9-11 in your Windows 10 Mail App

[image]

## EDIT

I've rechecked this thread and missed how people have generated a password and entered it not how I have done where I was only presented with 3 options.

So, I've done the same but except for the calendar app. Mail worked fine using this method so I thought this might, but no.

So I ran this command in PowerShell

`Get-Service -Name "*Credential*" | Format-List -Property Name, DependentServices`

This gave me a list of services and any dependent services which came back with

`CredentialEnrollmentManagerUserSvc_1c445e`

No sign of the other. Which makes me wonder if this is an account problem. My OS is tied to my MS online account.

Then I tried:

1. `Stop-Service -Name "Credential*" -Force -Confirm` in PowerShell
2. Click on Start and type `Services`.
   Right-click on `Services` and select `Run as Administrator`.
3. In the Services window, look for `Credential Manager Service` and **Stop** it.
4. Restart the computer and **Start** the Credential Manager Service and set it to **Automatic**.
5. Then the other is greyed out. So I tried `Set-Service -Name CredentialEnrollmentManagerUserSvc_1c445e -StartupType Automatic` in PowerShell but I didn't have the access to this, even though I'm the only admin.

Not sure what else to try but this info might serve others well.

See screenshot of the services window and PowerShell output for others to check if your results are similar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these. Nothing worked. Even a fresh install with current updates. Gmail already had IPOP and IMAP enabled. Option 2 and 3  from a 4-year old [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k39Rq4q91mw) did the trick. I had already tried the first option as that is what a Microsoft forum suggested with no luck.

> 1. How to reset the Mail app Settings
>
>    - Click Start button
>    - Settings.
>    - Click Apps.
>    - Click Apps & Features.
>    - Select the Mail and Calendar app from the list.
>    - Click on Advanced options.
>    - Click Reset button.
> 2. How to uninstall the Mail app on Windows 10
>
>    - Right-click start button and select Windows PowerShell, right-click and select >Run as administrator.
>    - Copy & Paste:
>      `Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps | Remove-AppxPackage`
> 3. How to reinstall the Mail app on Windows 10
>
>    - Open Windows Store and search for Mail and Calendar and click install.
> 4. How to install missing Mail app packages on Windows 10
>
>    - Type CMD in search box and right-click Command Prompt and click Run as >administrator.
>    - Copy and Paste:
>      `dism /online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:OneCoreUAP.OneSync~~~~0.0.1.0`
>    - Reboot your computer and Mail app should be working fine now.

*source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k39Rq4q91mw (video description)*