# Google account (mail / calendar) not syncing in Windows 10

Tags: sync, windows-10, google-accounts

I'm having a problem with the default Mail and Calendar apps in Windows 10. For a while I was able to sync my Google account emails (Gmail) and calendar in those apps, but about a week ago, it has stopped working: the calendar is empty (no events, and no calendars listed), and the emails that were already synced are still there, but syncing doesn't bring any new email.

I tried deleting my Google account from the mail (or calendar) app, by going to "settings -> accounts", and then re-creating the account. **I did that three times**. Each time I was able to complete the following steps:

1. enter my Gmail address,
2. then my Google account password,
3. then the confirmation code sent by SMS,
4. and finally got to the screen "Windows would like to..." (permissions listing), on which I clicked "Accept" (obviously).

The **first time**, I then got a Windows message "Something went wrong", followed by an error code (I didn't write it down).

The **second time**, I didn't get this error message, so it looked like the account was successfully created (it appeared in my accounts list in the settings of those apps), but nothing was synced: both apps (mail / calendar) remained empty. (I tried syncing manually by clicking the sync button in the mail app: still nothing, even though the app confirmed that it was "up to date".)

For my **third attempt**, I had found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/951270/how-to-solve-this-error-while-connecting-a-google-account-on-windows-10), so I went and created an "app password" in my Google account, specifically for those apps. But when I got to the password screen (step 2 described above) and entered this app password instead of my regular account password, I got an error message (from Google) asking me to enter my account password and **not** an app password. So I did that, and that got me exactly the same result as my second attempt (account created but nothing synced).

I also tried both answers given on the same question (first via "settings > accounts > add account > Other account", and second via "settings > accounts > add account > Advanced setup"), but none of them worked for me (again, account created but nothing synced).

Has anyone experienced the same problems? How can I make this work?

**UPDATE**: a few months back (early October 2015) I received an email from Microsoft inviting me to "reconnect to Google" (that was the title of the email). I ignored it for a while, but recently followed the steps in this email and now everything seems to be working fine. So I'm guessing that MS somehow fixed whatever bug it was.

Comment: Also having the same problem. There's also nowhere to change the password (i.e. not to delete the account, but to just change the password) - The question begs - how do you change a password for a GMail account on Mail for Windows 10 ? As far as I can ascertain, this cannot be done !! Heh Heh

Comment: Hey, have a look here :http://superuser.com/questions/951270/how-to-solve-this-error-while-connecting-a-google-account-on-windows-10?lq=1 This might work if you use the "Advanced Setup" rather than the Google  in the "Choose an Account" screen when adding an account

Comment: Yes, this link is already in my post. ;) I tried it with no success.

Comment: I'm curious about that email you got.  What did it have you do?  I'm having the same problem as you now.

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember (that was almost 4 years ago). I don't use those apps anymore on Windows 10 (instead I use Thunderbird). Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

That might have caused due to this privacy setting turned off. Go to **settings > Privacy > Calender** and turn on the settings “Let apps access my calender“. Also the other two settings. Try syncing the mail app. That should work.

Source: http://www.alltechflix.com/windows-10-mail-app-not-syncing-fix/

Comment: This. In my case, the Windows 10 Mail App did not have access to emails. (settings > Privacy > E-mail)

Answer (score 1):

First confirm if you have two step authentication in you Google account.
If YES follow these steps:

To have the Windows Mail app to work you have to generate a password for the Windows Mail app in your Google account at https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
Copy/paste this password into the password field of your Gmail account in the Mail app Settings/Accounts/Gmail
This needs to be done only once.

Also check in Windows 10 Settings/Privacy if you have in Contacts AND Calender the Mail and Agenda allowed access ON
If both are OFF the Mail app won't sync without throwing any error!!
Just one off the many bugs in Mail app!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem. My windows 10 native email app was working fine, but the windows 10 native calendar wasn't syncing with my google calendar account. I tried to delete gmail account on both the the calendar and email app but it did not work.

THE SOLUTION (at least for my case): I deleted the gmail account again on the windows apps (both email and calendar) and  went to **"windows settings > system > storage > temporary files"** and cleared the temporary files. After that, I added the gmail account on the windows app and it worked fine (it took some time to sync).

** my windows is in Portuguese, then i don't know if it's the correct translation to the English windows.**

I hope it help you, good luck!